# Variational Autoencoder for 4D-Input

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

Hello iam currently using the tensorflow.org Variational Autoencoder implementation.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae

I just tried to change the architecture in a way that it accepts batches of 6 images. 
I tried to adapt the code by myslelf and just change the Conv2D to Conv3D but that did not really work.
The original images are batches of 6 x 299 x 299 OCT images.
I reshaped them to 64 x 64.

```
class CVAE(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim):
    super(CVAE, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    # defines an approximate posterior distribution q(z|x)
    # outputs mean and log-variance of a factorized Gaussian 
    self.inference_net = tf.keras.Sequential(
      [
          tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(6, 64, 64, 1)), # (28, 28, 1)
          tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(
              filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(
              filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
          # No activation
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim),
       ]
    )

    # outputs p(x|z)
    self.generative_net = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
          tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6*16*16*32, activation=tf.nn.relu), # change with img_size (7,7,32)
          tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(6, 16, 16, 32)), # change with image size # (7,7,32)
          tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(
              filters=64,
              kernel_size=3,
              strides=(2, 2, 2),
              padding="SAME",
              activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(
              filters=32,
              kernel_size=3,
              strides=(2, 2, 2),
              padding="SAME",
              activation='relu'),
          # No activation
          tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(
              filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1, 1), padding="SAME"),
        ]
    )
```

```
InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'conv3d_5/Conv3D' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [?,2,13,13,32], [3,3,3,32,64].
```

```
def _parser(self, example_proto):
    # define a dict with the data-names and types we
    # expect to find
    features = { 'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string) }
    # parse the serialized data 
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    # decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type
    ima = tf.io.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.float64)
    ima = tf.reshape(ima, (6,299,299)) # (6,299,299)

    ## custom; ima is already a tensor
    ima = tf.expand_dims(ima, -1) # (6,299,299,1) 
    ima = tf.image.resize(ima, (64, 64)) 
    #ima = ima[0,:] # only 1st scan
    #ima = tf.squeeze(ima)
    #ima = tf.reshape(ima, (1,784)) #(6, 784)
    ima = tf.cast(ima, 'float32')
    # normalizing images
    ima = ima / 255
    print("Parser Format: {}" .format(ima))

    return ima # (28, 28, 1)
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. I am kind of new to neural networks.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: @thushv89 sorry i updated the question. After changing the kernel_size=(1, 3, 3) I got rid of it (because I still want to keep 6 images together for the latent space repsresentation). But now I am running into an other error... `TypeError: Invalid shape (24, 28, 1) for image data
`

Comment: It appears in this function:                                                                                    `def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
  predictions = model.sample(test_input)
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))

  for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
      plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
      plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
      plt.axis('off')

  # tight_layout minimizes the overlap between 2 sub-plots
  plt.savefig('image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))
  plt.show()`

Comment: Are your images any kind of special images (additional dimensions than height width channels)? Why are you switching to 3D convolution?

Comment: OCT images. Each patient gets 6 images (radial slices) at a time. I thought I have to use 3D convolutions because of the additional dimension i am adding.

Comment: I still don't see the need for 3d convolution. So you have 6 images with 64x64x1 (after resizing). You can still represent this as a 64x64x6 if you consider the number of images as the channels

Comment: @thushv89 sorry I did not know that this was an option. I tried your idea but I cant figure out how to organise the images so it fits your format. I added my parser function into the question. Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @thushv89 well it wasn't that difficult tbh but its in your suggested fromat. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @thushv89 well after training it seems like the images are now orederd in a 6x6 grid. So each image actually consists of 36 oct images. This was not really what I intended. I wanted the network to interpret each 6 scans as one input image and compute the loss to another image (6 scans as well) if that is kind of clear. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.